# This ᴀɴᴅ That musical act from the past

Tags: no-computers, music

Below is a fill-in-the-blanks three-part list
of variously-venerable musical acts of the form
“________ ᴀɴᴅ ʜɪs/ᴏᴜʀ/ᴛʜᴇ _________.”
The example of
“*Paul Revere* ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ *Raiders*”
has been filled in for starters.

Completion of blanks is meant to rely
purely on knowledge, clues, intuition and luck— perhaps
friends and relatives as well.
**Internet search and other written reference materials
are meant to stay out of play**,
which is why some attribution and explanation is expected.

Here are the “leaders” for the list’s **left column**,
in alphabetical order. 
Each of the three sub-lists is ordered alphabetically by first letters.

- Adam , Alvin , Bennie , Big Brother ,
  Bob Marley , Bobby “Boris” Pickett ,
  Bruce Springsteen , Captain Beefheart , Christine ,
  Country Joe , Derek , Diana Ross , Echo ,
  Elvis Costello , Fats Waller , Frankie Valli ,
  George Thorogood , Gerry , Gladys Knight ,
  Happy Kyne , Huey Lewis , Ian Dury , Iggy ,
  Joan Jett , Josie , Kool , Les Brown ,
  Mike ,  <s>**Paul Revere**</s> , Pearl Harbor ,
  Siouxsie , Sly , Smokey Robinson , Spanky ,
  Spike Jones , The Mamas , Tom Petty ,
  Toots , Woody Herman , Ziggy Stardust

And the musical-act name completions for the list’s **right column**,
in order of length:

- Ants , Fish , Gang , Gang [twice] , Jets ,
  News , Pips , Papas , Queens , Rhythm ,
  Dominos , Maytals ,  <s>**Raiders**</s> ,
  Stooges , Wailers , Banshees , Bunnymen , Miracles ,
  Supremes , Chipmunks , Mechanics , Pussycats ,
  Blockheads , Destroyers , Explosions , Magic Band ,
  Pacemakers , Attractions , Blackhearts , Mirthmakers ,
  Family Stone , Four Seasons , City Slickers ,
  Crypt‑Kickers , E Street Band , Heartbreakers ,
  Band of Renown , Holding Company ,
  Thundering Herd , Spiders from Mars

Relative lengths of blanks in the right column
indicate whether each right-column answer is longer or shorter
than its adjacent right-column answers.
This carries across the three sub-lists.

A FICTIONAL LEADER AND GROUP,
either made for television or merely mentioned in songs:
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ______________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ _____________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ______________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ _____________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ______________

NOT A LEADER AND GROUP,
where the “leader” is not one person, not even a person,
or the “group”  is not the group:
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ____________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ___________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ __________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ___________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ____________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ___________

AN ACTUAL LEADER AND GROUP:
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ _________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ __________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ___________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ___________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ __________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ _________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ __________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ʜɪs _________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ __________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ _________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ _________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ _________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ _________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ʜɪs _________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ________
Paul Revere ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ Raiders 
[both adjacent group names are longer]
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ _______
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ________
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ _______
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴏᴜʀ ______
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ʜɪs _______
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ _______
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ ______
__________ ᴀɴᴅ ᴛʜᴇ _______

Comment: Is this a puzzle? To me, this seems more like trivia, as in, there is no "figuring out", you just know the answer or you don't.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is plain trivia

Comment: This is pure trivia; perhaps interesting trivia, but not a puzzle.

Comment: I'm very sorry that you saw this as only trivia, @hexomino .
Where you go others follow.
It was meant as a trivium-based puzzle,
along the lines of numerous pop-culture based rebuses and riddles
that have not been closed.
I knew it would alienate many but mathematical puzzles,
one of your and my strengths, also exclude the majority of solvers.
There are clues in the group names
as well as in the left and right columns of the lists.
I'll get around to preparing a link-based suggestive case for reopening.

Comment: See above, @bobble.  I respect you so much but this time you didn't even try to solve it.

Comment: Thank you for recognizing the interesting content, @qwertyu63 !  It has. Again, see above.

Comment: Rebuses and riddles are puzzles because creative interpretations of the lines/pictures are required. (If none is required, I would and have voted to close as trivia). Also, trying to solve a puzzle is not a requirement to close it. Never has been, never will be.

Comment: Please do not overlook my bona fides, @bobble.  I steal puzzle books from whatever libraries remain. While solving self-affine transforms like no other.